# How to resize an image to be mobile-friendly?

Tags: html, css

For example, how would you create an image that is centered and takes up 100% of the page on mobile, but is left-justified and takes up no more than half the page on desktop?
Here's my current code:

```
.img{
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .img {
        text-align: left;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
```

Likewise, how would you code a block of text that is below the image on mobile, but wraps around the image on desktop?

Comment: `text-align` would refer to text which is a child element of the image, which is *impossible*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a simple solution using `float` to put the text next to the image.

You can add further styling to the text to get it how you want it.

Also, `text-align` cannot be added to an `<img>` but can be to a block element that holds and image, which will align it within the block. For example, I have created an `img-container` and aligned the image within this.

```css
.img-container {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .img-container {
    max-width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

  .text {
    max-width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="img" src="https://placekitten.com/500/500">
</div>

<p class="text">Some text below image on mobile and next to image on desktop.</p>
```